# PHP and Toad Oracle query results are different

Tags: php, oracle, toad

When using the same query, same user DB credentials, with Toad for Oracle and then with PHP function oci_fetch_assoc, data array returned by oci_fetch_assoc is missing in a few columns, and a few columns are missing alltogether. All expected is present in Toad results.

I googled and searched here, no solution.

Toad is using Instant Client - 11.2.0.1.0

**My PHP oci8 information**

OCI8 Support - enabled

Version     1.4.6

Revision    $Revision: 313688 $

Active Persistent Connections   0

Active Connections  0

Oracle Run-time Client Library Version  11.2.0.2.0

Oracle Instant Client Version   10.2

Temporary Lob support   enabled

Collections support     enabled

Answer (score 0):

If you run the exact same query in PHP and Toad and they return different results the only conclusion is that your PHP is ignoring a few columns of the resultset.

Comment: I'm var_dumping the array returned by the query in PHP, the columns simply aren't present there.

Comment: The code has already created the array by the time you dump it. If the code is creating an array for specific columns, it has already changed by the time you make the array.

Comment: Ok, so why has it changed the array? And there's no code that would alter the array, the array should just be raw query result.

Comment: How about you post the query that you are running in Toad and PHP and the code that PHP runs to create the output and we can have a look-see :)

Comment: I think I jumped the gun a bit, this is still an issue. I can't post the query itself as it's a work thing, but here's the php code:

Comment: @Mladen Don't take this as lawyers advice, but short of posting the the server address, username and password of the db you are hitting, I think that showing your query will be okay :)

Comment: I'd love to, but the db columns are very application specific, I wouldnt want to loose my job :) Tried to post the PHP code, but stackoverflow didnt accept my indentation. Basically this issue is about getting the same output as Toad, and I'll be tring to use fethc_all with oci_define_by_name as I don't see any other solution.

Comment: Fair enough. in that case I hope it works for you. The short version stands that your PHP code is doing something to the results returned by the query that your TOAD client isn't.

Answer (score 0):

When you use oci_fetch_assoc, only the fields with a value that is not NULL will be returned.
To work with this I fetch the columnnames with this code:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=oci_num_fields($parsed); $i++)
{
    $col = oci_field_name($parsed, $i);
    $columnNames[] = $col; // store column names in array
}
```

then my fetch function looks something like this:

```
function fetch()
{
    global $columnNames; // (I actually have a Query class so I use $this->columnNames)
    $row = oci_fetch_array($parsed, OCI_ASSOC);
    foreach ($columnNames as $colname)
        $row[$colname] = isset($row[$colname]) ? $row[$colname] : null;

    return $row;
}
```

edit: Another (less likely) possibility is that the missing columns are CLOBS. You need to fetch those with the OCI_RETURN_LOBS flag (see [oci_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-array.php))